# ReactJS change state of another class from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to understand the `state.props` to help me pass a value from a child to a parent. I have a `header component` (child) that when a link is clicked it should pass a value to a method inside the `App component` (parent). This method then sets the state of a value which is used for other things. I've tried binding the method inside the App.js file but that isn't working. I get the error when I click a link: `×
TypeError: _this.changeSearchState is not a function`

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {

changeSearch = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
   var type = this.value;
   this.changeSearchState(type);
}

render() {
return (
<header>
      <div className="float-right top-bar">
        <Link onClick={this.changeSearch} value="users" to="/users">Users</Link>
        <Link onClick={this.changeSearch} value="feedback" to="/feedback">Feedback</Link>
        ...
      </div>
</header>
)
}
}
export default Header;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    isOpen: false,
    dataType: ''
}
this.changeSearchState = this.changeSearchState.bind(this);
}
changeSearchState = (dataType) => {
 this.setState({
  dataType: dataType
 });
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to pass `changeSearchState` to the `Header` component as a prop.

In `render()` for **App.js**:

```
<Header
    changeSearchState={this.changeSearchState}
/>
```

Then to access it from **Header.js**:

```
changeSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = this.value;
    this.props.changeSearchState(type)
}
```

You can read more about components and props [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should update state just in **one** place. So you should update it in the `Parent` component and pass it down to the `Child`. You can access the method passed from parent to child like a normal prop. Something like this:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    isOpen: false,
    dataType: ''
}
this.changeSearchState = this.changeSearchState.bind(this);
}
changeSearchState = (dataType) => {
 this.setState({
  dataType: dataType
 });
}
render() {
  return (
    <Header changeSearchState={this.changeSearchState} /> //this is what you want!!!
  )
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {

changeSearch = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
   var type = this.value;
   this.props.changeSearchState(type); // call it here with this.props!!
}

render() {
return (
<header>
      <div className="float-right top-bar">
        <Link onClick={this.changeSearch} value="users" to="/users">Users</Link>
        <Link onClick={this.changeSearch} value="feedback" to="/feedback">Feedback</Link>
        ...
      </div>
</header>
)
}
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks, This solved the answer like the other, although he was 1 min earlier :)